# Querying a MySQL range using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, range

I have a `ref` field in my mysql table that holds values that look like '0-0-at-3267-201411041356'. The first part (0-0-at-3267-) varies in length and values and the second part (201411041356) is a date/time that references a creation date/time. Everything that this code is used for is checked to see if it falls within a certain date/time period, such as between 201409010000 and 201508312359.

Normally I can simply explode the data and then measure but for this instance it would make it too clunky. So what I want to do is use the `LIKE` function in my query like so `LIKE '%201411041356'` but I want to use it with the `>` and `<` symbols, so the full query looking something like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ref LIKE > '%201409010000' AND ref LIKE < '%201508312359'`

Any ideas would be most welcome! BTW, this has always been the way this data has been stored and there's lots of it so changing it is not an option.

Comment: Why would you need a LIKE if you're using greater and less than?

Comment: Because I need the wildcard too as the first part of the data isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use between on a substring, so something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE SUBSTRING(ref,-12) BETWEEN '201409010000' AND '201508312359'
```

Comment: Wow, this is a simple but effective solution and works perfectly. thank you!

Comment: Sometimes simplicity is the way forward

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE SUBSTRING(ref,-12) BETWEEN '201409010000' AND '201508312359'`
```

would work better for substracting last 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Because You wrote that first part may have different lenght so You have strip substring starting from the end.

So Your quwery may looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE
SUBSTRING('ref', -12) > $from
AND 
SUBSTRING('ref', -12) < $to
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to measure by date use:

```
left(right(ref, 12), 8)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show this within a query example please so I can see what you're doing here?

Comment: select * from my_table where left(right(ref, 12), 8) BETWEEN '20141104' AND '20141108'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b8154